# What's the right way to run a javascript function without getting the object to "jump" right after the page loads

Tags: javascript

I have simple page with an object that gets a "top" property from the javascript.

How do I run the function without getting things on my page to "jump" ?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


   function changeHeight () {
    //Gets height
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    //alert(h);
    console.log(h);

    var categories = document.getElementById("cat").offsetHeight; 
    //alert(categories);

    var x = 0.32 * categories;   

    var catTop =  h - x;


      //Gets cats
      document.getElementById("cat").style.top = catTop+"px";
    }



  </script>

</head>
<body onload="changeHeight()" onresize="changeHeight()">


<div class="main">

    <div class="cat" id="cat"></div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I used "onload" on the  tag to run the function. Which I know that's not so good.

Comment: so, you want another way to call the function, without using the onload attribute?

Comment: I want a way to run the function but without getting the "cat" div to jump from top to bottom in the after a second that the page loads..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object jumps because you move it after the DOM has been rendered. That's what `onload` does: Make sure the DOM is complete and all loading/rendering has happened.

There are two solutions:

1. Put the `script` element after the node.
2. Use CSS to position the element

The first solution looks like this:

```
<div class="main">

    <div class="cat" id="cat"></div>
    <script>...</script>

</div>
```

At the time when the script is executed, the necessary DOM nodes are there. Unless your layout is complex, the offsets should be correct at this time. Note that many browsers start rendering while the page is loading. So there still might be a jump but less often, depending on the complexity of the page, browser optimizations, etc.

The second solution is to wrap your element in a container where you set the margin/padding until the `cat` element is naturally positioned correctly. The `0.32` would be translated to `32%`. You need another element around it which has the correct height but which isn't visible.

To final solution should give `body` `height: 100%`, then add two containers inside. One for the content and the other to position the `cat` element. You will need to play with `position` style. Then

```
#cat { top: 32% }
```

should do the trick.

Comment: do I leave the part `<body onload="changeHeight()" onresize="changeHeight()">` the same as it is ?

Comment: For the first solution, you need to drop the `onload="changeHeight()"`. Instead, you call `changeHeight()` at the end of the `<script>` element. For the second solution, you can remove both.

Comment: Ok, and how do I get the `onresize` keep working? 
keeping it on the body tag is ok?

Comment: Just learn how to code the right way. I'm new and I want to do things "right".